# Base Error Rate

Tags: error, baseline

I am working for my final exam and I saw this sample question:
[image: Dataset]

Given this dataset,  Assume we have the following gender detection problem, given the observed hair length and height (both discrete random variables) that are observed from a distance. Answer the following questions according to the data given below. Use proper probability notations. Note sample index is just there to facilitate counting, it is not an attribute.

And the question is: What is the base error rate for this problem?

Can somebody explain me what is the meaning of "base error rate"?

Comment: Question is unclear, is there some text berfore this?

Comment: there were 2 more questions about this data before this one. But they are not related

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of "base error rate", what is the context for this task? What branch of probability? Is this base rate also known as prior probabilities?

Comment: Actually, this was a question from Machine Learning exam so I guess it is related with machine learning

Comment: If this is for your final exam, presumably the term should have come up in class and be in your notes, no?

Comment: Thats the problem, I have searched the textbook and lecture notes but I could not find it :D

Comment: We have an answered question about "base error rates" at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138127/esl-base-error-rate-question.  Would that be pertinent to your situation?

Answer (score 1):

A model's "Error Rate" means how wrong the model's predictions are. In our case, where the predicted value is assumed binary (is_male=True/False), the error rate would simple equal to the percent of wrong answers - every time the model guessed Male when the true value was Female or vice versa.

The Base Error Rate would be the error rate of the "simplest" model, which all other model will be compared to. For a binary classification problem, the base model would simply be a "majority vote" - predicting the majority class will yield the lowest expected error rate among all of the "simple" models (e.g. Predict the minority class, or pick a random class).

In the given exercise, the value of the base error rate would be 30% - since the base model would predict "Male", and be wrong 3 out of 10 times.